# Return Distinct Object From List

Tags: android, arraylist, hashset

Using `return new ArrayList(new HashSet(object));` should return a list of unique objects. Suppose my object has two variables, say `String1` and `String2`.

How would i restructure the code to as to get unique objects based on one of the variables, say `String1` such that if two items have the same value as the `String1` variable, only one of them is returned?

Comment: How do you decide which object to return?

Comment: Let's say I have an object Song(String artist, String title) and the items in the list are, Song(Rihanna, Diamonds), Song(Rihanna, Umbrella) and so on. I only want to return one song that has Rihanna and not both.

Comment: Well, if it doesn't matter which one gets returned, then I'd just create a Set for the artist names, iterate over the List, `add()` each name to the Set, and remove the object from the List if `add()` returns `false`.